# setSelected to listview item at coordinates after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview that has a fixed top & bottom padding. What I want to to is

> When scrolling is stopped, check the coordinates at the middle of the
>   listview and assign selected state to true.

What I have tried to do is using

1. **AbsListView.OnScrollListener** to check if the scroll stateis SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, then do the assigning.
2. **pointToPosition** to get the item index, this is the adapter position
3. Use **getChildAt(index)** and setSelected(true)

The problem here is when I do **getChildAt**, at some point, the app will be broken, maybe because the **getChildAt** only works with visible items. I have tried following approaches too:

- Used **getView**'s **getAdapter** then assigning, but no luck.
- Doing calculation with **getFirstVisiblePosition**, then using **getChildAt** but the issue here is the number of visible items which are not constant.

OnScrollListener:

```
public class fromListScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        switch (scrollState) {
            case AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                index = view.pointToPosition(view.getWidth()/2,view.getHeight()/2);
                view.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(index, 0, 500);
                if (actionUp == 1){
                    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            index = view.pointToPosition(view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2);
                            view.getChildAt(index).setSelected(true);
                        }
                    }, 600);
                    actionUp = 0;
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution while doing another project. I did not specify what type of View I should be applying selected state to. Following is my solution.

```
index = view.pointToPosition(view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)toList.getChildAt(index - toList.getFirstVisiblePosition());
ll.setSelected(true);
```